# Proof that G is Abelian given $xy=zx\implies y=z$ for $x,y,z \in G$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Suppose G is a group and that for all $x,y,z\in G$, we have that $xy=zx \implies y=z.$ Prove $G$ is Abelian.

“*Proof*”:

Since $xy=zx \implies y=z$, $\forall x,y,z\in G$, we have that for $y=z=t, xt=tx$. Hence any two arbitrary elements of $G$ commute. Thus, we see by definition, that $G$ is Abelian.

QED

Is this proof correct  and rigorous?

Comment: Not a proof except if you meant $y=tx$ and $z=xt$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just Ihf's proof simplified:

By the given condition:

$$x(yx)=(xy)x \Rightarrow yx=xy$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a valid proof:
$$
xy = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}yx
\implies
y = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}y
\implies
e = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}
\implies
yx = xy
$$

Comment: Very nice proof, but much longer than it needs ;) If you want to copy the shorter version I can delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,g \in G$, then $xGx^{-1}=G$ trivially, Hence $xgx^{-1} = g'$ for some $g' \in G$. But then $xg=g'x$ implies $g=g'$. Hence $xg=gx$. Since $x,g$ are arbitrary this completes the proof.